# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me please to solve this..

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Running:

```
c:\projects\mysite>python manage.py sql polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 340, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 295, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 221, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 128, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 57, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 72, in load_app
    mod = __import__(app_name, {}, {}, ['models'])
  File "c:\projects\mysite\..\mysite\polls\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Poll(models.model):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: @jazzrai - Is this correct? Would you mark it as answered?

Comment: @jazzrai: Would you mind accepting an answer? This'll also help future readers!

Answer (score 77):

It's called models.Model and not models.model (case sensitive). Fix your Poll model like this -

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: @MichaelDorst: Because this question was seen many times, this answer is correct, and the answer was not accepted. It is a flaw of SO, in my opinion, that the answer cannot be voted as correct by the community.

Answer (score 8):

I also got the same error but I noticed that I had typed in Foreign**k**ey and not Foreign**K**ey,(capital K) if there is a newbie out there, check out spelling and caps.

Answer (score 3):

Searching

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BinaryField'

landed me here.

The above answers did not solve the problem, so I'm posting my answer.

[`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.6/#binaryfield-model-field) was added since Django 1.6. If you have an older version, it will give you the above error.

You may want to check the spelling of the attribute first, as suggested in the above answers, and then check to make sure the module in the Django version indeed has the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says in the last line: the module `models` in the file `c:\projects\mysite..\mysite\polls\models.py` contains no class `model`. This error occurs in the definition of the `Poll` class:

```
class Poll(models.model):
```

Either the class `model` is misspelled in the definition of the class `Poll` or it is misspelled in the module `models`. Another possibility is that it is completely missing from the module `models`. Maybe it is in another module or it is not yet implemented in `models`.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that by looking at the stack trace it was trying to load my own script in place of another module called the same way,i.e., my script was called random.py and when a module i used was trying to import the "random" package, it was loading my script causing a circular reference and so i renamed it and deleted a .pyc file it had created from the working folder and things worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In `class poll`, you inherited your class from `models.model` but there's no module in models called that name.

Because Python is case sensitive, you need to use the capital `Model` instead of `model`.

```
class poll(models.Model):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this
class Poll(models.model):

to this

class Poll(models.Model):

## problem was models.model ---> models.Model

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow! Please don't repeat what other people have already said.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I have given from django.db import models in my admin.py file. After modifying it to from MyAppName import models, my issue is resolved. (Though I don't understand y I am supposed to import models from my app and not django.db) Also, one more thing just verify how you have defined your primary key. Make sure to add this DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField' in your setting.py file if you haven't exclusively defined your primary key.

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).