# terminal problem "'django.forms.models' has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

[What's appear on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brkOJ.png)

I cant solve this error when I write the command

`python manage.py makemigrations polls`

Comment: Please share full file of models.py

Comment: You should import `django.models`, not `django.forms.models`.

Comment: check this. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456867/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-model)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs :

```
from django.db import models

class Model(models.Model):
    # Your model fields
```

Comment: from django.db import models
i just had to add that part , i added the "class" part and it made a another error , thanks alot